# "Table not found here" error exporting emacs to HTML

Tags: html, emacs, export, org-mode

I get an error in the minibuffer `Table not found here` when exporting to HTML using the following commands: 

`C-c C-e (to export, of course)
C-v     (visible only)
h       (for HTML)
h       (to create an HTML file from output. Also tried "o" here; same result)`

Any insights?

Comment: This error probably comes from [table.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/textmodes/table.el#L2966). Can you enable debugging (`toggle-debug-on-error`) and check the call stack? Also providing a minimum example, orgmode version, emacs version will help. Also try running `emacs -q` to avoid reading configuration files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. `toggle-debug-on-error` wrote a lot of info to minibuffer; froze my emacs (first time ever freezing, interesting). 

Ended up expanding each section, one by one, then exporting visible `C-v` until the issue presented itself. 

Ended up being a table with a stray `+------------+` appended at the end (incomplete table?). I killed that line, then export worked as intended.